# do not nest defun (use flet or labels), sbcl REPL does not report all conditions (warnings)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Tests performed on SBCL 1.3.1

I define function `xx` inside of function `xxx`. (Originally `xx` was recursive and there were invariants used from the `xxx` closure. However the recursion is not important here, `xx` just returns `t`) `xxx` only calls `xx`. Hence `xxx` is expected to return `t` also.

`xxx` is called twice inside of the function `call-xxx`. For this issue to manifest (that of the condition) it must be called twice. Though no state is shared between the calls, so why this would matter is curious.

`call-xxx` is passed as `#'call-xxx` to apply, inside of a `handler-case`. It takes no arguments, so it is just applied to nil. `handler-case` pulls it out and says it throws a condition.

When `xx` is instead defined outside of `xxx`, there is no condition, and the expected result of t is returned. This is shown in the second part of the code shown below, where we have `ww`, `www`, `call-www`, etc. Also when `handler-case` is not used, there is no exception reported by the REPL.

[This example is stubbed out from a testing framework, thus when `call-xxx` is said to throw an exception the test fails. Yet, when the test runs manually (see `run-call-xx`) it passes without an exception, thus creating a contradiction and making it difficult to debug the apparently failed test.]

What causes this condition? Should the condition handler call be different? Is this an SBCL bug?

Here is the code:

```
(defun test (test-function)
  (handler-case (apply test-function '()) (condition () ':exception))
  ;;;  (apply test-function '()) ;; returns t, no exception
  )

;;---------------------------------------------------------------
;; throws exception, but shouldn't (?)
;;
  (defun xxx ()
    (defun xx () t) ; note comments, should be a flet or labels form
    (xx))

  (defun call-xxx ()
    (xxx)  ;; #'xxx must be called twice for the exception to appear
    (xxx)
    t)

  ;; call-xxx throws exception when run from test, but shouldn't
  (defun run-test-call-xxx ()
    (test #'call-xxx))

  ;; no problem here, call-xxx returns t when called directly
  (defun run-call-xxx ()
    (call-xxx))

;;--------------------------------------------------------
;; works fine  
;;  pulled out the nested definition of #'ww from #'www
;;
  (defun ww () t)

  (defun www ()
    (ww))

  (defun call-www ()
    (www) 
    (www)
    t)

  (defun run-test-call-www ()
    (test #'call-www))
```

And here it is running:

```
§sbcl> sbcl
This is SBCL 1.3.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (load "src/test-xxx")

T
* (run-test-call-xxx)

:EXCEPTION
* (run-test-call-www)

T
*
```

*added* here is the test function redefined to do the reply without the handler. I've done this so as to see what the REPL reports.

```
(defun test (test-function)

  ;;; -> this does not get handled
  ;;; (handler-case (apply test-function '()) (serious-condition () ':exception))

  ;;; -> this triggers the handler
  ;;; (handler-case (apply test-function '()) (condition () ':exception))

  (apply test-function '()))
```

And this is what happens in the REPL:

```
§sbcl> sbcl
This is SBCL 1.3.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp....
distribution for more information.
* (load "src/test-handler.lisp")

T
* (run-test-call-xxx)

T
*
```

As you can see the REPL does not print a warning.

Note comments, `defun` is only top level, so one handle recursion within a closure using `flet`. With `defun` the internal function will be defined upon each entry, though a warning is issued, that isn't making it to the REPL (though handler case does see it, that is what is going on here)

```
(defun f (s too-big-for-stack-invariant)
    (defun r (s) ;; note comments, should be a labels form, not defun
        ;; changes s and checks for termination
        ;; makes use of the very large invariant data
        ...
        r(s))
   ;; some stuff making use of r(s)
   )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems with the code:

1. `defun` in Common Lisp defines top-level definition. Even if it appears inside another function (this way it's different from Scheme's `define`). Thus, function `xx` is redefined every time `xxx` is called.
2. Condition `condition` will catch even something "not worth mentioning" (see [CLHS](http://file:///home/alexey/Dropbox/References/Programming/Lisp/HyperSpec-7-0/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm) on `handler-case`). Since redefinition of `xx` produces a warning, it will catch it. If you don't do the `handler-case` warning will show in REPL but the correct result will be produced.

Comment: Adding to this, the correct way to define a function inside another is to use either `labels` or `flet`. They work much like `let`, but with functions instead of variables.

Comment: Warning does not show in the REPL - if it had my post would be different.  Is there an SBCL switch or something I should have thrown to see this warning?  I've edited to add the transcript above.  jkiski has anticipated my next question. (wow great information thank you!)

Comment: @user244488 To be honest, I don't know about the warning switch. My default setup of SLIME produces `; SLIME 2015-06-01STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::XX in DEFUN` and
`STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::TEST in DEFUN` in REPL.

Answer (score 1):

I think here the problem is that you are intercepting any condition no matter what. SBCL in this cases signals a condition about `xx` being redefined with `defun` (not an error, but a warning as it's possibly unintended).

Changing the code to:

```
(defun test (test-function)
  (handler-case (apply test-function '())
    (condition (x)
      (print x)
      ':exception)))
```

will show `#<SB-KERNEL:REDEFINITION-WITH-DEFUN {1002BE3E93}>`

The logical problem is that you should not declare to be able to handle conditions you don't know: you should handle the conditions you know and let others to be handled by who knows. A condition may be resolved by the proper handler by just letting the program to continue running (as it would be the case here).

This is the major difference between conditions and exceptions: unwinding is performed only later if the handler decides it's the right thing to do. With say C++ instead once an exception is thrown all is already lost at lower call stack levels when the exception is handled.

Comment: are you a MOSTEK guy?  Yes, thank you for the print form above, that makes it much clearer.  This is the fix that will go into the test bench. The test bench did correctly point out there is a problem with the original code (I just didn't understand what was happening), as redefining a function on every call is not a good thing.  But would it not be appropriate for the test bench to catch everything?